# Microscope Objective / NA, F/#, Exit aperture - when are they non-intuitive?

Tags: optics, microscopy

Numerical aperture (NA) $= sin(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the half-angle (see:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_aperture)

F/# $= \frac{f}{D}$ (same reference as above)

where F/# is the f-number, $f$ is the focal length, and $D$ is the lens diameter.

An infinity corrected microscope objective is essentially an infinite conjugate.  Therefore:

$\frac{D}{f} = 2 \times tan(\theta)$

Olympus objectives are typically designed such that the power is related to the focal length using the following:

$f = \frac{180mm}{P}$

where $P$ is power.

Taking this to the logical conclusion reaches a paradox.  Use a 60X objective with a $NA = 0.95$.

$f = \frac{180mm}{60x}$ = 3.0 mm

$\theta = a sin(0.95)$ = 71.8 deg

$D = 2\times tan(\theta) \times f$ = 18.2 mm!

The lens diameter appears too large.  There are no microscope objectives this large.  Although I can accept that the optical prescription can increase (decrease) the marginal ray, the exiting beam from a point source at the object plane is collimated.  Under what conditions can this beam be smaller than the "lens diameter"?

*By the way, I've modeled some microscope objectives in Zemax using US Patents.  Some obey these equations above, some do not.*

Comment: Please use MathJax for your formulas and equations.

Comment: @user3533030 I edited the formulas to include MathJax. Are they accurate?

Answer (score 1):

For a lens obeying the Abbe sine condition, e.g., any well corrected microscope objective, $\frac{D}{f} = 2\times\sin\theta$. The explanation for this is in the Wikipedia article you refer to. It is probably the cause of the discrepancy in your results for high NA objectives (where $\sin\theta\not\approx\tan\theta$).

Answer (score 0):

I agree.  Since then, I have tried to build a model (Zemax) of the objective.  It seems that microscope objectives have a principal sphere instead of a principal plane.  This addresses the first order ray tracing.  I'm not really sure how far this model can be used.

Assuming a real objective has no aberrations, can the principal sphere / plane model be used for off-axis imaging?

Answer (score -1):

An other explanation could be that the F# is D/f where D is the diameter of the entrance pupil of the optical system (cf http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-number), here an microscope objective.

Thus the 18.2 mm calculated here could correspond to a plane inside the objective. In this case 18.2mm is a plausible lenght since most of the objective I know have an external diameter superior to 20mm.

erratum : my bad F# = f/D thanks Kyle. But my main poin remain valid : D is the pupil diameter therefore while being a proper physical dimension, it may not be related to any physical object (i.e lenses), it's a product of the overall optical assembly.

Comment: *An other explanation could be that the F# is D/f...* Your link says otherwise.